# What is the typing system of Java Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, drools

I want to store attributes of an entity with a hashmap. The value is either an built-in `int` or a `List` of `String`.

```
name : "John Smith"
attributes:
   "seniority" : (int) 7
   "tags" : List<String>("asst_prof","cs_dept")
   "another_attrib" : (int) 3
```

I am confused about the **typing system** of the Map, after reading diverging tutorials Google gives. The closest I came to was something that used `String` keys and `Object` values.

---

**Question:** How do I create a Hashmap and insert values of `int` or `List<String>`, so that when I fetch the value, it is **typecast (identified as a member of type)** as either an `int` or a `List<String>`, not an `Object`.

I am depending on Drools Expert package, which [accesses values from maps by itself](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta2/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e4051), so the typecasting is **not in my control**.

```
// Same as attributes.get("jsmith").isValid()
Person( attributes["jsmith"].valid )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  Either you use the basic form of Map that stores and returns the values as Objects, then you have to cast them yourself:

```
Object value = map.get(key);

if (value instanceof List<String>) {
    List<String> myList = (List<String>) value;
}
```

With ints, you can't store the primitive type int, but it will be auto-boxed to an Integer. So you would have to check for `instanceof` Integer, then call `.intValue()` on the `Integer` Object.

To get the Objects returned as the Objects they are then you have to use Generics, but you can't mix types.  So you would have to create a Map of `List<String>` attributes and another for int attributes.

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing is an example of an [algebraic data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_type). Unfortunately, these are not supported in Java.

You'll need to use Map and cast the value to either Integer (int), or List yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In Drools, you can disable the compile time type safety for specific types if you want. In this case, Drools will work as a dynamically typed language and will resolve the types at runtime for the given type. Example:

```
declare Person
    @typesafe(false)
end

rule X
when
    Person( attributes["seniority"] == 7 ) // resolving seniority to Number
...

rule Y
when
    Person( attributes["tags"].size() > 1 ) // resolving tags to List
...
```